# Unable to establish an SSH tunnel using Redis Desktop Manager

Tags: ssh, ssh-tunneling, ssh-agent, redis

I am trying to connect to an Elasticache Redis Server via an AWS Ubuntu instance and using an ssh tunnel. When I try to configure Redis Desktop Manager  to connect via an ssh tunnel and provide credentials and .pem file, I have authentication issues. However, this same .pem file doesn't create issues when I try to connect via shell. Am I missing something here ? should I change the file permission (as for now it is 400).

This a screenshot on the errors  shown on the RDM system log
[image]

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure you use the correct username ? AWS uses different usernames depending on Linux distro. AFAIK, they generally use 'ec2-user' except for Ubuntu installations where they use 'ubuntu'.

Comment: Yes I am using a correct username. I have been already  able to connect via shell

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure you are using a private key in .pem format? For Windows users, the Redis Desktop Manager documentation states the following:

> for Windows users:
>
> Your private key is must be in .pem format.