# Unable to create a proper PEM for Redis Desktop Manager

Tags: ubuntu, ssh-tunneling, redis

On Ubuntu, I have a problem to establish a connection to redis server using SSH tunnel **and** SSH key with Redis Desktop Manager (RDM).

What are the symptoms?

- I can connect to the server where redis is running using "plain" `ssh` and my `id_rsa`,
- other utilities which use either the SSH agent or keys in `.ssh` can connect to this server and create tunnels (e.g. DB apps),
- I can connect with RDM to redis servers using SSH tunnel **and** password (so the question is not a duplicate of [Unable to establish an SSH tunnel using Redis Desktop Manager](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/256912/unable-to-establish-an-ssh-tunnel-using-redis-desktop-manager)); but this is not a perfect solutions, because I would rather use private/public keys authorization,
- I cannot convert keys in `.ssh` to a *working* PEM format required by RDM: any PEM files I've generated using different methods I googled are rejected by RDM with a message `Connection: Disconnect on error: SSH Connection error(Authentication Error): Unable to extract public key from private key file: Unable to open private key file`,
- I tried entering either a path to `id_rsa` (`~/.ssh/id_rsa`) or just a path to a directory where my private key is stored (`~/.ssh`).

So, does anyone have an idea how to properly convert my SSH keys to a PEM format RDM needs and accepts?

Comment: Can openssl read the private key?  **Please do not post the results, but run the command** `openssl pkey -in ~/.ssh/my_key.pem -text` .... And what format does the key say it's in... **Do post this result** `grep BEGIN ~/.ssh/my_key.pem`

Comment: yes, openssl can read the file, `grep` returns `-----BEGIN RSA PRIVATE KEY-----`

Comment: I'd like to add, that I tried to put both public and private key into the same file. I did not work as well.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

That's a known issue of RDM: https://github.com/uglide/RedisDesktopManager/issues/4230

Workaround: copy your id_rsa file into a directory without "." in its name...

Comment: Please note, that the file *must not* be sym-linked. It has to be copied or hard-linked.

Answer (score 1):

If you installed rdm as a snap you will need to run the following command.

```
sudo snap connect redis-desktop-manager:ssh-keys
```

This is documented at http://docs.redisdesktop.com/en/latest/install/#ubuntu-archlinux-debian-fedora-centos-opensuse-etc which is linked to the Github issue at https://github.com/uglide/RedisDesktopManager/issues/4230 which is in the solution provided by @nimai